# R: substitute multiple column names in a data frame and keep their numerical value

Tags: r, dataframe, string-formatting

I have a data.frame named dataOrder, where columns correspond to sample names (n=384) and rows correspond to gene entities (n=180200).

```
                sample1  sample2   sample3   sample4   sample5   sample6
ENST00000000233       9        0   3499.51         0         0         0
ENST00000000412       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000000442       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000001008       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000001146       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000002125       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
```

I would like to substitute part of the column name (str `sample`) to five different names: t1_, t2_, t3_, t4_ and t5_.

I tried to use gsub function to substitute names:

```
nameVec <- names(dataOrder)
nameVec <- gsub("sample","t2_",nameVec[1:96])
nameVec <- gsub("sample","t3_",nameVec[97:163])
nameVec <- gsub("sample","t4_",nameVec[164:259])
nameVec <- gsub("sample","t5_",nameVec[260:333])
nameVec <- gsub("sample","t1_",nameVec[334:384])
names(dataOrder) <- nameVec
head(dataOrder)
```

However, all of my column names were substituted to NA.

How I can substitute 'sample' string in title and keep numerical index in columns?

```
                   t1_1    t1_96     t2_97    t2_163    t3_164    t3_259
ENST00000000233       9        0   3499.51         0         0         0
ENST00000000412       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000000442       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000001008       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000001146       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
ENST00000002125       0        0      0.00         0         0         0
```

Here is reproducible data example (written by @RuiBarradas):

```
mydf <-
structure(list(target_id = c("ENST00000000233", "ENST00000000412", 
"ENST00000000442", "ENST00000001008", "ENST00000001146", "ENST00000002125"
), sample1 = c(9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sample10 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sample100 = c(3499.51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sample101 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sample102 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), sample103 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("target_id", "sample1", "sample10", 
"sample100", "sample101", "sample102", "sample103"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:"))

result <- mydf[-1]
row.names(result) <- mydf$target_id
result
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are substituting all the vector with only segments of it. Try instead

```
nameVec <- names(dataOrder)
nameVec[1:96] <- gsub("sample", "t2_", nameVec[1:96])
nameVec[97:163] <- gsub("sample", "t3_", nameVec[97:163])
nameVec[164:259] <- gsub("sample", "t4_", nameVec[164:259])
nameVec[260:333] <- gsub("sample", "t5_", nameVec[260:333])
nameVec[334:384] <- gsub("sample", "t1_", nameVec[334:384])
names(dataOrder) <- nameVec
```